# How to resolve URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly error

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm new in Android development and I'm developing an Android App using Eclipse. I want to implement a  functionality to Synchronize database on Dropbox. Now am getting,

```
   11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:155)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:126)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:149)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:115)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.example.smereceipt.NewReceiptScreen2.onCreate(NewReceiptScreen2.java:87)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<init>(NativeLib.java:33)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:11)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     ... 19 more
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DropboxSync: findLibrary returned null
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(NativeHttp.java:446)
11-12 13:35:30.985: E/AndroidRuntime(4555):     ... 21 more
```

Error.

My code is like this,

**Manifest.xml**

```
        <!-- For Dropbox -->
        <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="db-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
```

Also i have added **build.gradle** Its like,

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files("$buildDir/native-libs/native-libs.jar")
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip) {
    destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
    baseName 'native-libs'
    extension 'jar'
    from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
    into 'lib/'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn nativeLibsToJar
}
```

When i execute

```
mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);
```

this code am getting the error.

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace for the exception.

Comment: A full stack trace would help confirm, but the most likely cause of that exception would be if the native libraries didn't make it into your app package, or are out of sync.  If you took an SDK update recently, make sure you copied over all of the new .so files as well as the .jar.

Comment: @atwyman. I have updated the error. Now am getting this exception. Tn that exception db-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is my app id.

Comment: the dropbox key in java code must match the key in manifest. Check please.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto
I have Updated the same App key now am getting error. 
My error Log is updated in my question.

Comment: try clean n build then .. Also try to check your library if it's placed partially ..

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Thanks For your help. I have resolved by adding ".so" file libs.

Answer (score 3):

Change the line "db-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" to "db-jd7ld246chdlkej" with your app key.

```
  <activity
  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
  <intent-filter>
    <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
    <data android:scheme="db-jd7ld246chdlkej" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception (Couldn't load DropboxSync: findLibrary returned null) means that libDropboxSync.so cannot be found at run-time.  I'm not familiar with the gradle build process, but I'd suggest taking a look at the contents of native-libs.jar.  The .so might be missing, or maybe it doesn't include the right platform (armeabi is the most common) or the structure of the jar file might not be right (it should contain a sub-directory for each platform, with a .so file in each subdir).